# Trim characters in Java

Tags: java, string, trim

How can I trim characters in Java?
e.g.

```
String j = “\joe\jill\”.Trim(new char[] {“\”});
```

*j* should be

> "joe\jill"

```
String j = “jack\joe\jill\”.Trim("jack");
```

*j* should be

> "\joe\jill\"

etc

Comment: What should `\\\\joe\\jill\\\\\` should return? `joe\\jill` ??

Comment: @Oscar yes. Like the trim in .net

Comment: I don't think this operation is called trimming...

Comment: But I just search trim char to find this question, hooray.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) has a great [StringUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) (org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils). In `StringUtils` there is a `strip(String, String)` method that will do what you want.

I highly recommend using Apache Commons anyway, especially the Collections and Lang libraries.

Comment: Really nice solution.

Answer (score 52):

This does what you want:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String a = "\\joe\\jill\\";
    String b = a.replaceAll("\\\\$", "").replaceAll("^\\\\", "");
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

The `$` is used to remove the sequence in the end of string. The `^` is used to remove in the beggining.

As an alternative, you can use the syntax:

```
String b = a.replaceAll("\\\\$|^\\\\", "");
```

The `|` means "or".

In case you want to trim other chars, just adapt the regex:

```
String b = a.replaceAll("y$|^x", ""); // will remove all the y from the end and x from the beggining
```

Comment: I think you need to add the `\\ `, i.e. `"\\y$|^\\x"`

Comment: don't you mean `"\\\\+$"`?

Answer (score 20):

## `CharMatcher` – Google Guava

In the past, I'd second [Colins’ Apache commons-lang answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2088900/642706). But now that Google’s [guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is released, the [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) class will do what you want quite nicely:

```
String j = CharMatcher.is('\\').trimFrom("\\joe\\jill\\"); 
// j is now joe\jill
```

[CharMatcher](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher) has a very simple and powerful set of APIs as well as some predefined constants which make manipulation very easy. For example:

```
CharMatcher.is(':').countIn("a:b:c"); // returns 2
CharMatcher.isNot(':').countIn("a:b:c"); // returns 3
CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'b').countIn("a:b:c"); // returns 2
CharMatcher.DIGIT.retainFrom("a12b34"); // returns "1234"
CharMatcher.ASCII.negate().removeFrom("a®¶b"); // returns "ab";
```

Very nice stuff.

Comment:  Do check out the [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) in Google Guava. Slick stuff. Clever use of Predicate syntax. Makes it easy to specify which of the various definitions of whitespace, invisible, and control characters you have in mind. The doc links to an interesting spreadsheet listing some [various definitions of whitespace](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pd8dAQyHbdewRsnE5x5GzKQ).

Answer (score 9):

Here is another non-regexp, non-super-awesome, non-super-optimized, however very easy to understand non-external-lib solution:

```
public static String trimStringByString(String text, String trimBy) {
    int beginIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = text.length();

    while (text.substring(beginIndex, endIndex).startsWith(trimBy)) {
        beginIndex += trimBy.length();
    } 

    while (text.substring(beginIndex, endIndex).endsWith(trimBy)) {
        endIndex -= trimBy.length();
    }

    return text.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
}
```

Usage:

```
String trimmedString = trimStringByString(stringToTrim, "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `removeStart` and `removeEnd` from Apache Commons Lang [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hand made for the first option:

```
public class Rep {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
       System.out.println( trimChar( '\\' , "\\\\\\joe\\jill\\\\\\\\" )  ) ;
       System.out.println( trimChar( '\\' , "joe\\jill" )  ) ;
    }
    private static String trimChar( char toTrim, String inString ) { 
        int from = 0;
        int to = inString.length();

        for( int i = 0 ; i < inString.length() ; i++ ) {
            if( inString.charAt( i ) != toTrim) {
                from = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for( int i = inString.length()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ){ 
            if( inString.charAt( i ) != toTrim ){
                to = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return inString.substring( from , to );
    }
}
```

Prints

`joe\jil`

`joe\jil`

Comment: Boss, in your last line it would be return inString.substring( from , to + 1 );

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String trim(String value, char c) {

    if (c <= 32) return value.trim();

    int len = value.length();
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value.toCharArray();    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] == c)) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] == c)) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length())) ? value.substring(st, len) : value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
private static String trim(String string, String charSequence) {
        var str = string;
        str = str.replace(" ", "$SAVE_SPACE$").
                  replace(charSequence, " ").
                  trim().
                  replace(" ", charSequence).
                  replace("$SAVE_SPACE$", " ");
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Easy and straightforward solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Amended by answer to replace just the first and last '\' character.

```
System.err.println("\\joe\\jill\\".replaceAll("^\\\\|\\\\$", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built in function to trim based on a passed in string.   Here is a small example of how to do this.   This is not likely the most efficient solution, but it is probably fast enough for most situations, evaluate and adapt to your needs.  I recommend testing performance and optimizing as needed for any code snippet that will be used regularly.   Below, I've included some timing information as an example.

```
public String trim( String stringToTrim, String stringToRemove )
{
    String answer = stringToTrim;

    while( answer.startsWith( stringToRemove ) )
    {
        answer = answer.substring( stringToRemove.length() );
    }

    while( answer.endsWith( stringToRemove ) )
    {
        answer = answer.substring( 0, answer.length() - stringToRemove.length() );
    }

    return answer;
}
```

This answer assumes that the characters to be trimmed are a string.  For example, passing in "abc" will trim out "abc" but not "bbc" or "cba", etc.

Some performance times for running each of the following 10 million times.

`" mile ".trim();` runs in 248 ms *included as a reference implementation for performance comparisons.*

`trim( "smiles", "s" );` runs in 547 ms - approximately 2 times as long as java's `String.trim()` method.

`"smiles".replaceAll("s$|^s","");` runs in 12,306 ms - approximately 48 times as long as java's `String.trim()` method.

And using a compiled regex pattern `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("s$|^s");`
`pattern.matcher("smiles").replaceAll("");` runs in 7,804 ms - approximately 31 times as long as java's `String.trim()` method.

Comment: "answer.length - trimChar.length - 1" actually

Comment: Not really optimized. I wouldn't use this.

Comment: @BrettWidmeier I think I've got this write.   `trim( "smiles", "les" )` yields `smi` and `trim( "smiles", "s" )` yields `mile`.

Comment: I can't imagine a more *inefficient* way to solve this problem.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey I agree that it is not the most efficient solution, but context is helpful.   On my machine, 10 million runs of `trim( "smiles", "s" );` take 547ms and 10 million runs of `" mile ".trim()` take 248 ms.   My solution is 1/2 as fast as `String.trim()` and still 10 Million runs complete in about half a second.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey The regex numbers are that `"smiles".replaceAll("s$|^s","")` run 10 million times takes 12,306 ms (~48 times slower than `String.trim()` and ~24 times slower than my implementation)

Comment: @Alex: I will take back my down-vote if you add a note that it should be optimized for the common-case of trimming a single character; I will up-vote it if you amend the code to so optimize (given that what is being asked for a is a re-usable library method).

Comment: (and by "a single character" I mean any number of a single character from either end... IOW, when trimChar is length 1).  Also trimChar is a bad name for that param... should likely be trimString or trimValue.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: I appreciate the feedback.  I'll add a comment about optimizing for the problem domain, but I didn't see any context for how this would be used in the original question or how many characters would be stripped (one example had a single character, and one example had a string).  Good call on the name of trimChar.

Comment: Your comparison to regex is not really fair or realistic; since the form used will compile the regex every time.  If one were doing this frequently, one would create the regex and reuse the matcher, as the JavaDoc suggests: `An invocation of this method of the form str.replaceAll(regex, repl) yields exactly the same result as the expression Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)`.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: Great point!  I took the regex example from @PauloGuedes code.  I added numbers for the compiled regex version to my timing section.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that there is no ready to use java api that makes that but you can write a method to do that for you.
this [link](http://www.javafundu.com/2009/02/trim-prefix-and-suffix-any-characters.html) might be usefull

Comment: sure it is :D
i meant a trim function that takes string as the question says

Answer (score 0):

I would actually write my own little function that does the trick by using plain old char access:

```
public static String trimBackslash( String str )
{
    int len, left, right;
    return str == null || ( len = str.length() ) == 0 
                           || ( ( left = str.charAt( 0 ) == '\\' ? 1 : 0 ) |
           ( right = len > left && str.charAt( len - 1 ) == '\\' ? 1 : 0 ) ) == 0
        ? str : str.substring( left, len - right );
}
```

This behaves similar to what String.trim() does, only that it works with '\' instead of space.

Here is one alternative that works and actually uses trim(). ;) Althogh it's not very efficient it will probably beat all regexp based approaches performance wise.

```
String j = “\joe\jill\”;
j = j.replace( '\\', '\f' ).trim().replace( '\f', '\\' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

I think it's about as efficient as it reasonably can be.  It optimizes the single character case and avoids creating multiple substrings for each subsequence removed.

Note that the corner case of passing an empty string to trim is handled (some of the other answers would go into an infinite loop).

```
/** Trim all occurrences of the string <code>rmvval</code> from the left and right of <code>src</code>.  Note that <code>rmvval</code> constitutes an entire string which must match using <code>String.startsWith</code> and <code>String.endsWith</code>. */
static public String trim(String src, String rmvval) {
    return trim(src,rmvval,rmvval,true);
    }

/** Trim all occurrences of the string <code>lftval</code> from the left and <code>rgtval</code> from the right of <code>src</code>.  Note that the values to remove constitute strings which must match using <code>String.startsWith</code> and <code>String.endsWith</code>. */
static public String trim(String src, String lftval, String rgtval, boolean igncas) {
    int                                 str=0,end=src.length();

    if(lftval.length()==1) {                                                    // optimize for common use - trimming a single character from left
        char chr=lftval.charAt(0);
        while(str<end && src.charAt(str)==chr) { str++; }
        }
    else if(lftval.length()>1) {                                                // handle repeated removal of a specific character sequence from left
        int vallen=lftval.length(),newstr;
        while((newstr=(str+vallen))<=end && src.regionMatches(igncas,str,lftval,0,vallen)) { str=newstr; }
        }

    if(rgtval.length()==1) {                                                    // optimize for common use - trimming a single character from right
        char chr=rgtval.charAt(0);
        while(str<end && src.charAt(end-1)==chr) { end--; }
        }
    else if(rgtval.length()>1) {                                                // handle repeated removal of a specific character sequence from right
        int vallen=rgtval.length(),newend;
        while(str<=(newend=(end-vallen)) && src.regionMatches(igncas,newend,rgtval,0,vallen)) { end=newend; }
        }

    if(str!=0 || end!=src.length()) {
        if(str<end) { src=src.substring(str,end); }                            // str is inclusive, end is exclusive
        else        { src="";                     }
        }

    return src;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

10 year old question but felt most of the answers were a bit convoluted or didn't quite work the way that was asked. Also the most upvoted answer here didn't provide any examples. Here's a simple class I made:

https://gist.github.com/Maxdw/d71afd11db2df4f1297ad3722d6392ec

**Usage**:

```
Trim.left("\joe\jill\", "\") == "joe\jill\"

Trim.left("jack\joe\jill\", "jack") == "\joe\jill\"

Trim.left("\\\\joe\\jill\\\\", "\") == "joe\\jill\\\\"
```