# Java equivalent for Python's str.strip()

Tags: java, string

Suppose I would like to remove all `"` surrounding a string. In Python, I would:

```python
>>> s='"Don\'t need the quotes"'
>>> print s
"Don't need the quotes"
>>> print s.strip('"')
Don't need the quotes
```

And if I want to remove multiple characters, e.g. `"` and parentheses:

```python
>> s='"(Don\'t need quotes and parens)"'
>>> print s
"(Don't need quotes and parens)"
>>> print s.strip('"()')
Don't need quotes and parens
```

What's the elegant way to strip a string in Java?

Comment: The String class has a replace() method. It should fit your needs.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2088900/593709) is a detailed discussion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Suppose I would like to remove all `"` surrounding a string

The closest equivalent to the Python code is:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^\"+", "").replaceAll("\"+$", "");
```

> And if I want to remove multiple characters, e.g. `"` and parentheses:

```
s = s.replaceAll("^[\"()]+", "").replaceAll("[\"()]+$", "");
```

If you can use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), there's [`StringUtils.strip()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Comment: +1 For handling multiple characters as requested. It still creates two new Strings, though.

Comment: @AdamMatan: I think Common Lang's `StringUtils.strip()` is the preferred method. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

The [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library has a handy utility for it. The library contains [`CharMatcher.trimFrom()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#trimFrom-java.lang.CharSequence-), which does what you want. You just need to create a `CharMatcher` which matches the characters you want to remove.

Code:

```
CharMatcher matcher = CharMatcher.is('"');
System.out.println(matcher.trimFrom(s));

CharMatcher matcher2 = CharMatcher.anyOf("\"()");
System.out.println(matcher2.trimFrom(s));
```

Internally, this does not create any new String, but just calls `s.subSequence()`. As it also doesn't need Regexps, I guess its the fastest solution (and surely the cleanest and easiest to understand).

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can do it like :

```
s = s.replaceAll("\"",""),replaceAll("'","")
```

Also if you only want to replace "Start" and "End" quotes, you can do something like :

```
s = s.replace("^'", "").replace("'$", "").replace("^\"", "").replace("\"$", "");
```

OR if simply put :

```
s = s.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").replaceAll("^'|'$", "");
```

Comment: it have modified my answer accordingly..!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a time waste, creating two new Strings instead of one?

Comment: Note that strings are "immutable", thus it is not sufficient to simply do ''' s.replace("\"","") '''. You must reassign the variable 's' to the resulting string 's'.

Comment: And the answer u "accepted", did it do any Good than mine..??..i gave u 3 different ways to go around..!!..at least , you can upvote my answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

This replaces `"` and `()` at the beginning and end of a string

```
String str = "\"te\"st\"";
str = str.replaceAll("^[\"\\(]+|[\"\\)]+$", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
new String newS = s.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

replace the double-quote with a no-character String.