# Regex for extracting a substring

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the string from the input string with "/" removed from the beginning and the end (if present).

For example :

Input String : `/abcd`
Output String : `abcd`

Input String : `/abcd/`
Output String : `abcd`

Input String : `abcd/`
Output String : `abcd`

Input String : `abcd`
Output String : `abcd`

Input String : `//abcd/`
Output String : `/abcd`

Comment: Google is faster than ask question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String abcd1 = "/abcd/";
    String abcd2 = "/abcd";
    String abcd3 = "abcd/";
    String abcd4 = "abcd";
    System.out.println(abcd1.replaceAll("(^/)?(/$)?", ""));
    System.out.println(abcd2.replaceAll("(^/)?(/$)?", ""));
    System.out.println(abcd3.replaceAll("(^/)?(/$)?", ""));
    System.out.println(abcd4.replaceAll("(^/)?(/$)?", ""));
}
```

Will work.

Matches the first `(^/)?` means match 0 or 1 '/' at the beginning of the string, and `(/$)?` means match 0 or 1 '/' at the end of the string.

Make the regex `"(^/*)?(/*$)?"` to support matching multiple '/':

```
String abcd5 = "//abcd///";
System.out.println(abcd1.replaceAll("(^/*)?(/*$)?", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Method without regex:

```
String input  = "/hello world/";

int length = input.length(),
    from   = input.charAt(0) == '/' ? 1 : 0,
    to     = input.charAt(length - 1) == '/' ? length - 1 : length;

String output = input.substring(from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more guess: `^\/|\/$` for replace RegEx.

Comment: This one: `^\/+|\/+$` will match `/////abcd///////` as well - just in case, but not mentioned in the initial request.

Comment: Why downvote? the initial answer seems to match the initial request))) "with "/" removed **from the beginning and the end (if present)**"

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
 String original="/abc/";
 original.replaceAll("/","");
```

Then do call trim to avoid white spaces.

```
original.trim();
```

Comment: Only from the start and the end of the string, this would remove all.

Comment: Following his examples seems only char '/' at start/end

Answer (score -2):

This one seems works :

```
/?([a-zA-Z]+)/?
```

Explanation :

/? : zero or one repetition

([a-zA-Z]+) : capture alphabetic caracter, one or more repetition

/? : zero or one repetition