# how do i remove first and last occurrence of the sentence in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a following line : `|A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11|` and I want to remove the first and last occurrence of `|`.

I have to check first if the `|` is available at `first and last`

I am sure that this will bring me some down votes but really don't know how to go about.

**EDIT**

I also have to check for the following :

```
A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11| and |A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11 and there is no
```

possibilities for `||` that is why I did not want to give any explanation for the same.

thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java

Comment: I think it needs regex solution, not substring or indexOf.

Comment: @justhalf this is not duplicate of what you have provided :)

Comment: You want to remove the first and last `|`, if they are available as the first and last characters, right?

Comment: Probably you can give more example. What is your expected output on this: `AB|CD|EF|`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the first occurrence of `|` or simply remove the first character? do you want a sentence like `AB|BC|` changed to ABBC?

Comment: he mentioned first and last occurrence

Comment: @BalajiD: But he also mentioned "check if `|` is available at first and last", which is confusing.

Comment: @Anto Why did you tag this question with regex, if you do not require a regex solution?

Comment: @balajiD : it is confusing. Does he want to remove `|` if it is the first character in a sentence or does he want to remove the first occurence of `|`

Comment: @justhalf.  yup, but i think he mentioned occurrence.

Comment: All, I want to remove `|` if it is the first one and if available in the last one also

Comment: So, does Jerry's answer hit exactly your question?

Comment: @Anto: You should edit your question to include your expected output for these cases: `|AB|BC|CD|`, `|AB|CD|EF`, and `||AB|CD|EF|`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comments lead me to believe that you want to do this:

```
String result = subject.replaceAll("^\\||\\|$", "");
```

This will change each of the following strings:

```
|A|B|C|
|A|B|C
A|B|C|
A|B|C
```

to the same string `A|B|C`.

See it on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/oN1mP4).

Answer (score 6):

You can perhaps use the regex:

```
^\\|(.*)\\|$
```

And replace by `$1`:

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/FBygro)

If the start and end of the string are not both `|`, there'll be no replacement.

EDIT: As per your last comment, if you want to remove the `|` if it's either at the start and/or at the end of the string, then use an OR operator (there's too many `|` in that question I think =P):

```
^\\||\\|$
```

Replace by nothing (empty string `""`)

---

EDIT2:

If the first regex is closer to what you need but also want to remove multiple pipes, add quantifiers:

```
^\\|+(.*)\\|+$
```

If the second regex (in first edit) is what you need but also want to remove multiple pipes, add quantifiers again!

```
^\\|+|\\|+$
```

Note that the replacement strings remain the same in both cases

Comment: According to the comments, it's possible that only one side of the string is a `|`, and that should be removed.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes, I saw it just a while ago... The question wasn't well formulated after all :(

Comment: According to his comments "if | is not available at first and last than what will happen if I use your code?" and his question "I have to check first if the | is available at first and last" I think OP wants to remove the characters if they are present both at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @justhalf But in another one of his comments, OP has: "All, I want to remove | if it is the first one and **if** available in the last one also` And I only added one option, depending on what he's really looking for. He can pick the one he needs.

Comment: Yes, the question is quite unclear. How if there are multiple pipes at the end like `|AB|CD|EF||`?

Comment: @justhalf I can add yet another option for him to choose =P

Comment: Haha, I hope he wants to convert `|AB|CD|EF||` into `AB|CD|EF`, for which `StringUtils.strip(input,"|")` would be very elegant, and that this question would be indeed a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java haha

Comment: @Jerry the code is working if the `|` exist `first and last` and the code is not working for `A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11|` and `|A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11`

Comment: @justhalf Might be the case. Sometimes, we our mindreading powers aren't far reaching.

Comment: @Anto Use the second regex I mentioned in my answer. Or use TimPietzcker's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` from `java.lang.String` package

```
    String s="|A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11|";
    s=s.substring(s.indexOf("|"),s.lastIndexOf("|"));
    System.out.println(s);    //Prints A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11
```

Comment: I thinks he wants a regex solution

Comment: he didn't mention, just he tagged

Comment: @kark if `|` is not available at first and last than what will happen if I use your code?

Comment: put dot in between the variable and lastIndexOf

Comment: @anto ..this `s=s.substring(s.indexOf("|"),s.lastIndexOf("|"));` is for removing the first and last occurance of a line..As your point if first is not occur, will take from the next occurrance of same String

Comment: This will also remove `|`s that aren't at the very start/end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
String input = "|A|B|C|D|100|E|GEN|smsplus|11|11|11|";
input = input.substring(1, input.length()-1);
```

or use [StringUtils.removeStart, removeEnd](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#removeStart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
StringUtils.removeStart(input, "|");
StringUtils.removeEnd(input, "|");
```

or

```
StringUtils.strip(input, "|");
```

Comment: @newuser..do you know `|` where will occur in a line

Comment: If you want to use StringUtils, you can use StringUtils.strip(input,"|")

Comment: @kark the questioner gives the input string. for that only i did that

Comment: @newuser.fine..good one for this question..i accept the edited answer

Comment: @newuser: You can use `StringUtils.strip(input,"|");`, you don't need to separate them into `stripStart` and `stripEnd`

Comment: @justhalf I think `remove...` method just suits the requirement. `strip(...` somewhat differs on it.

Comment: @Anto: if you really want to remove `|` at the beginning OR at the end, then `StringUtils.strip(input, "|")` is the best.