# How do I separate strings with a comma and a space without having them being put before it?

Tags: java, string, append

Beginner programmer here.

I have to append strings of file names together and have come up with the following methods:

```
class ConsLoItem implements ILoItem {
    Item first;
    ILoItem rest;

    ConsLoItem(Item first, ILoItem rest) {
        this.first = first;
        this.rest = rest;
    }

public String images() {
    if (this.rest.equals(new MtLoItem()))
    {
        return this.first.images();
    }
    else
        return this.first.images() + ", " + this.rest.images();
    }
}
```

and keep getting the same results, with:

", jesse.jpeg, " when I expect "jesse.jpeg".

Any ideas on how to remove the ", " from the beginning and end of the file name?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java

You could use replaceAll() method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652687/strip-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-java-string

Comment: Show def of class MtLoItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `images` method, like so

```
public String images() {
    if (this.rest.equals(new MtLoItem())) {
        return this.first.images();
    } else { // missed a brace here.
        if (this.first.images().length() > 0) {
          return this.first.images() + ", " + this.rest.images();
        }
        return this.rest.images();
    }
}
```