# Save "(key, value)" strings from file to map using java regex

Tags: java, regex, collections, hashmap

I am able to read the content from file

```
(abcd, 01)
(xyz,AB)
(pqrst, 1E)
```

And I want to save this content to `map` as

```
Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("abcd","01");
map.put("xyz","AB");
map.put("pqrst","1E");
```

**Help me to get the content as Map using regex in java**

Comment: post what you have tried?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java, and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java can be of help here.

Comment: which version of Java do you use ? The flow is reading from file and save in a map right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\(([a-z]+), ([0-9A-Z]+)\\)$");
Map<String, String> map = Files.lines(path)
    .map(pattern::matcher)
    .collect(toMap(x -> x.group(1), x -> x.group(2)));
```

Match group one is `[a-z]+` - key.
Match group two is `[0-9A-Z]+` - value.
Change group patterns on your needs.

**Note**: regex is a powerful mechanism. If or, to say correctly, when your input data get complex - your pattern will grow and become inapprehensible.

Comment: Thanks I got the it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can read each line with a `BufferedReader.readLine()` or similar. Call that String `line`. Then to drop the brackets:

```
line = line.substring(1,line.length()-1);
```

Then all you want is a split:

```
String[] bits = line.split(",");
map.put(bits[0], bits[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is about using regexp, but assuming this is not a class assignment etc the solution doesn't require a regexp. A short solution that also handles multiple values per key:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = Files.lines(Paths.get("data.txt")).map(s -> s.replace("(", "").replace(")", ""))
                .collect(groupingBy(s -> (s.split(","))[0], mapping(s -> (s.split(",", -1))[1].trim(), toList())));

System.out.println(map);
```

Will print the resulting map as:

```
{xyz=[AB], pqrst=[1E], abcd=[01]}
```

Explanation:

```
Files.lines(...) //reads all lines from file as a java 8 stream
map(s-> s.replace) // removes all parenthesis from each line
collect(groupingBy(s -> (s.split(","))[0] //collect all elements from the stream and group them by they first part before the ","
mapping(mapping(s -> (s.split(",", -1))[1].trim(), toList()) //and the part after the "," should be trimmed, -1 makes it able to handle empty strings, collect those into a list as the value of the previously grouping
```

Alternate replace, instead of two simple replace to remove ( and ) you can use

```
s.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "")
```

Not sure which is most readable.

Comment: It is better to do `s.replaceAll("^\\(|\\)$", "")` to drop only outer brackets.