# How to pull information from a text document then print it out

Tags: java

I would like to ask how I can pull information from a txt document ( my txt document contains like

> Baggins, Bilbo, < bilbobaggins@bagend.com >, Y
>
> Baggins, Frodo, < frodobaggins@bagend.com >, N

I have tried some stuff. I would also like to know how to store each part in a variable so i can edit them in a string builder/ use.trim to get rid of white spaces.

This is what i tried:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;     
import java.lang.SecurityException;       
import java.util.Formatter;               
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;  
import java.util.Scanner;



/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class pullingEmails {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     // open contacts.txt, output data to the file then close contacts.txt
     try (Formatter output = new Formatter("contacts.txt")) {
         while (input.hasNext()) { // loop until end-of-file indicator
            try {
               // output new record to file; assumes valid input
               output.format("%s %s %s %s", input.next(),  
              input.next(), input.next(), input.next());
            } 
            catch (NoSuchElementException elementException) {
           System.err.println("No email address: " );
           input.nextLine(); // discard input so user can try again
        } 




     }
  }
  catch (SecurityException | FileNotFoundException | 
     FormatterClosedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(1); // terminate the program
      } 
   } 
}
```

I am not the best at Java and this is a new concept. I basically need it to print out what is in the file

> Gamgee, Samwise, donleaveimsamwise@theShire.com,Y
>
> ```
>                 // every email has < > around them I will remove once i know how to pull the information correctly)
> ```
>
> Baggins,Drogo,drogobagginstheshire.com,N
>
> Erling,,erling@theshire.com,Y
>
> Fortinbrass, Took,,Y

example of if statement for exception (not 100 percent sure how to format this):

```
if No email address
system.err.println("No email address: Chester, Steve,, N");

if (!email.contains("@"))
system.err.println("Invalid email address: "<simon#gmail.com>". Missing @ symbol.");

if invalid character //(only capital, lowercase, and @ symbol aloud)
system.err.println ("Invalid character '%' at position 4 in last name: "Robe%tson")
```

My current output does not work. I tried to follow an example i had but that one was asking for information to put in the file at first. not sure how to read what is in a file already, print it out then be able to store each part in a variables like firstName, lastName, Email, Sub etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) for how to read files in Java.
As each line seems to consist of comma separated values, you can just use [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to get the individual values as array. Using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (or alternatively a for-each loop) you can clean those values, e.g. using [strip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) to remove whitespaces and [replaceAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088037/trim-characters-in-java) to remove the brackets.
For converting the array back into a line, you could use [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-). You can collect the lines using a `String` or better a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Here is an example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    Files.lines(Path.of("test.txt")).forEach(x -> {
        String[] split = x.split(",");
        split = stream(split).map(y -> {
            String cleaned = y.strip().replaceAll(">$|^<", "").strip();
            return cleaned;
        }).toArray(String[]::new);
        String email = split[2];
        // TODO: other data
        if (email.isBlank()) {
            System.err.println("No email address");
        }
        // TODO: other checks
        sb.append(String.join(", ", split));
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String result = sb.toString();
```